# Родительный или винительный падеж

Tags: падежи, существительные

В предложении "Зимой в лесу не увидишь **медведей, барсуков, ежей**" нужно определить падеж выделенных существительных. Учителя утверждают, что падеж винительный. Ученик настаивает, что — родительный. Он аргументирует это тем, что (1) при замене одушевленных медведей, барсуков и ежей на неодушевленные существительные становится очевидным родительный падеж, например: "Зимой в лесу не увидишь (кого? чего?) ягод, грибов, тропинок", и что (2) есть влияние отрицательной частицы НЕ по аналогии с "Вижу кошелек, но не вижу денег".

Кто прав? Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Интуитивно чувствуется родительный. Обосновать не могу.  "Барсуки" и в винительном и в родительном совпадают. После "не вижу" может идти и родительный и винительный. Хотя "не вижу ничего" гораздо распространённее, чем "не вижу ничто". Последнее тоже иногда употребляется но гораздо реже. Здесь почитайте http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xlv-upravlenie/ss-201-padezh-dopolneniya-pri-perehodnyh-glagolah-s-otricaniem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Во втором ответе** я предлагаю подумать над выбором падежа в двух предложениях:

1. *Ты что, не видел настоящей **белки**?*

Почему здесь Р.п., ведь это одушевленное существительное?

2. *Ты разве не видел **белку**?  Вот сейчас по тропинке пробежала.*

А здесь В.п., что соответствует правилу Розенталя.

В каком-нибудь предложении ошибка?

Comment: Не-не, так плоховато. Родительный подходит, если "никакой" можно добавить. Предложение из вопроса как раз такое.

Comment: Вам первое предложение не нравится?  Да если я добавлю усиление отрицание, то это будет классический Р.п. :  Ты что, никогда не видел настоящей белки? И в заданном предложении тоже Р.п. Или нет?

Comment: Проблема в том, что "настоящей" вносит конкретику, в то время как родительный подразумевает любой объект. И ещё: если подходит только "какой-то", то винительный: *Ты что, никогда не видел [какую-то] ("никакую" не подходит) белку?*

Comment: Вот у моих "белок" все точно так. Если ОБЩЕЕ суждение, то Р. п.  А когда речь идет о КОНКРЕТИКЕ (ту белку, которая сейчас пробежала), то нужен В.п. Об этом и Розенталь пишет. В заданном предложение тоже общее суждение, нет конкретики, поэтому отрицание задает Р.п.

Comment: Не совсем, в первом примере смысл такой: *Ты что, никогда не видел какую-то из настоящих белок?* Сравнить: *Зимой в лесу не увидишь белки.* Ну не звучит у меня, выше указано, из-за чего.

Comment: Сравнить: *Он не нашёл [какую-нибудь] белку. Здесь не найти [никакой] белки.*

Comment: Не звучит - это ваши трудности. Я вам объясняю правила Розенталя. У него конкретика на первом месте. А примеры с одушевленностью тоже касаются конкретных людей (там других  примеров, с животными, и нет). Поэтому для В.п.  одушевленность должна дополняться конкретикой, а иначе отрицание задает Р.п. Это мое мнение, основанное на понимании правила, а не только  на звучании.  Вот в этом плане надо дополнить бы Розенталя. А так надо читать литературу и проверять падежи, где это можно сделать по окончанию (ж.р. ед. ч.)

Comment: Дело в том, что Розенталь не случайно говорит только о винительном (мы сейчас об одушевлённых говорим). Если мы хотим уйти от этого правила, то должно подразумеваться слово "никакой", потому что именно оно наиболее характерно для родительного. Это как бы обход правила. Если бы падежи были равноправными (это не так), то Розенталь бы об этом сказал.

Comment: И ещё: если бы правило с одушевлёнными касалось только конкретики, то его бы не было, был бы просто первый пункт про конкретику. Включите логику.

Comment: Раньше писали так: Ты не любил моей Дуни.  Сейчас пр людей так не скажут (действует конкретика!).  А остальные темы в процессе развития. Читайте литературу, приводите примеры.  Факты красноречивее логики (недаром логика и софистика рядом ходят). Давайте на этом остановимся.  Мне нужна классика 20 века.

Comment: Ну да, то старомосковская норма, и она может влиять на вас (по понятным причинам). А сейчас что: без прилагательных перед существительным (потому что они немного вносят конкретику, что портит стилистику) и отрицать всех, а не говорить (например, спрашивать) о каком-то (что тоже немного вносит конкретику и портит стилистику).

Comment: То есть должно быть абсолютное отсутствие конкретики, чтобы обойти правило Розенталя. Но и в таких случаях винительный тоже подходит.

Answer (score 3):

**Учитель всегда прав)))**

В соответствии с правилом Розенталя, для **одушевленных** предметов при отрицании используется **В.п.** (отрицание не действует).

Можно проверить по ед.числу : здесь не увидишь (кого?) белку, лисицу (В.п).
Во мн.числе (кого?): медведей, барсуков, ежей.

**Для неодушевленных и неконкретных** предметов при отрицании используется Р.п.: не увидишь (чего?) ягоды, гриба (Р.п.). Во мн.ч. (чего?): ягод, грибов.

**Правило:**

2. Винительный падеж, ослабляющий значение отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:

(1) при указании **на конкретный объект** («именно этот предмет, а не вообще какой-то»): не отрецензировал рукопись, которую ему прислали; не выпила молоко, которое ей оставила мать. Например: Он не отвергнул тогда с презрением эти сто рублей (Достоевский); Не наклоняй знамя-то... (Горький);

(2) при выражении дополнения **одушевленным существительным**, в частности собственным именем лица, например: Ты не любишь мать (Л. Толстой); ...Не пожалеет ни папу, ни маму (Горький); Анна Николаевна не обманула Марью Александровну... (Достоевский); Недомогание не покидало Козьму еще долго (Бунин).

[§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141486/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----).