# Дефисное или раздельное написание?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

*Говорил с такими **фальшиво()позитивными** нотками в голосе.

**Агрессивно()горький** запах подпортившихся продуктов стоял в комнате.

Он запомнился мне своим **неприятно()правильным** поведением.*

Как быть в подобных случаях? Нужно смотреть, относятся ли оба прилагательных в равной степени к существительному – и тогда через дефис? Оценивать, характеризует ли первое слово второе – и тогда пишем раздельно?

Comment: Ещё слитно может писаться.

Comment: В третьем примере стилистика не очень, "неприятно" не очень подходит. Используют это: *слишком; чересчур; до отвращения*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Общий план решения**

В принципе предложенное решение верное, но надо помнить вот о чем.

(1) **Сочинительная связь** в подобных темах может обозначать как независимые (однородные) признаки, так и неоднородные (основной признак и его оттенок). Произносится такое сложное прилагательное в одно слово (с основным и вспомогательным ударением).

(2) Если первая часть является **наречием** с раздельным написанием, то оно обозначает **степень признака**  прилагательного. Произносится как словосочетание с подчеркиванием  наречия.

(3) Решение в этой теме не всегда однозначное и может быть **авторским**, например:

**Раздельно:** откровенно насмешливый взгляд  (насмешливый до откровенности) – степень проявления признака. **Дефис:** откровенно-насмешливый взгляд, независимые признаки, можно вставить союз И.

**2. Решение задачи**

(1) *Говорил с такими **фальшиво-позитивными** нотками в голосе.*
Здесь оттенок фальши в позитиве, дефисное написание.

Раздельное написание подходит меньше, так как выделить ударением наречие "фальшиво" сложно в предложении такой структуры. Это тоже приходится учитывать при решении задачи. При **дефисном** написании у нас **два ударения** в сложном прилагательном (основное и вспомогательное).

(2) ***Агрессивно-горький** запах подпортившихся продуктов стоял в комнате.*
Решение аналогичное (дефис), агрессивный оттенок в горьком запахе.

(3) **Он запомнился мне своим **неприятно правильным** поведением.**
Здесь скорее наречие со значением степени признака (правильное до неприятности).  Раздельное написание, ударение на первом слове.

Comment: Есть в правилах про этот оттенок?

Comment: А то!  Я правила не придумываю, у меня все честно, почти как у вас.  Розенталь, пункт 10, 11.  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49   Тогда и у меня к вам вопрос. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472845/Родительный-или-винительный-падеж  Мы долго обсуждал эту тему, и вам нетрудно будет сравнить два предложения в моем втором ответе. Сделайте уж одолжение. Ну и вывод можно сделать: кто там прав, ученик или учитель? Как вы думаете? Нужен ваш честный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

В справочнике Розенталя есть пункт с следующим содержанием:

18. Возможно различное написание одних и тех же определений в зависимости от их понимания. Ср.:

мещански-провинциальные манеры (‘провинциальные с оттенком мещанства’) — мещански провинциальные манеры (‘по-мещански провинциальные’);

уродливо-жалкая поза (указывается признак с дополнительным оттенком) — уродливо жалкая поза (‘жалкая до степени уродливости’);

То есть ответ примерно следующий:

‟**Фальшиво позитивными** нотками в голосе” пишется без дефиса, так как фальшива позитивность, а не нотки.
‟**Агрессивно-горький** запах подпортившихся продуктов” – тут (я не уверен) возможны варианты с дефисом и без.
‟Он запомнился мне своим **неприятно правильным**” – нет дефиса, так как замысел в том, что неприятна правильность, а не поведение.